Probability of choosing a constant polynomial
Suppose we have a polynomial $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$
where all the coefficients are whole numbers which includes Zero.
Suppose we now randomly choose the values of these coefficients then:
(A) What is the probability that the polynomial becomes a constant polynomial?
(B) How would the probability change if we extend the set from which we choose coefficient to integers, rational numbers and finally real numbers?
Context :
There is nothing specific that led me to this thought.
It is relevant to me because I am curious about this.
My genuine question was with the intention to learn more.

I don’t know much about probability theory at all, but I feel like the probability of this for all mentioned sets of numbers is nearly zero as these sets are not finite. Would love to know why I’m wrong, though.

@codeing_monkey Yes but the number of possible outcomes is also infinite so I think the probability will be a finite number

@AarushSaharan: FYI, this is equivalent to working over $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ or wherever the support of the coefficients that you assume). You need to endow the underlying space with a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ -- e.g., Uniform over some compact domain, or Gaussian, etc. Then, your question is reduced to $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{a}\in \mathcal{S})$, where $\mathbf{a}:=(a_0, a_1,\ldots,a_{n})$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is the line spanned by $(1,0,\ldots,0)$. In other words, you have probability mass distributed across the space and you ask how much is concentrated on the line.

I don't know much about continous probability as I have so far only studied discrete probability theory but is there any way that can be used here in case of real numbers

@AarushSaharan: Yes, we can endow the real line, or higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces, or infinite dimensional spaces (or any set you can think of) with a probability measure. A probability measure is a map that assigns a value between 0 and 1 to any (measurable) subset of the set of discussion. The set of discussion does not need to be "discrete". For example, $\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)=\int_{A} f(x) dx$, where $f$ is nonnegative and $\int_{[0,1]} f(x)dx=1$ conforms to a probability measure over the interval $[0,1]$-- in this case, the probability of the event $A\subset \left[0,1\right]$.

You will learn about it in due time -- stick to formal probability theory and measure theory.

That type of Integration is what I was referring to in my answer last section , @AugustoSantos , which will eventually give $0$ when we have Uniform Distribution , which was implicit in OP Question.

@Prem: When you extend from the discrete to the real line (or from a discrete dense subset to its closure) you have to be a bit careful. This can be done, e.g., via defining a "sample-mean" of diracs centered at the rationals and showing that the discrete measure converges weakly (or in distribution) to the integral. Further, just showing that "$P\rightarrow 0$" is not enough. But, I believe the spirit of your answer is what the OP was expecting.

(1) Extending to real requires care : Correct , that is why I did not elaborate it in my answer : It is a totally new question well beyond what OP was expecting. (2) Spirit is what OP was expecting : Correct , without Distributions & Details , @AugustoSantos , $P \to 0$ is the simplest answer !

@Prem: It is Ok, I understand.

I do not understand why this question is closed? It was genuine and did attract some nice answers. As for additional context, there is nothing specific that led me to this thought. It is relevant to me because I am curious about this.

No worries , Just want to add one last Point : OP is not aware of Continuous Case where we involve Integration between limits for the range of values like $\int_{L_1}^{L_2}{\cdots}$ , @AugustoSantos , which has $L_1=L_2=0$ for most of the Co-efficients here : Most Distributions will make that Integral $0$ , hence we will end up with $P \to 0$ over-all.

@Prem: Thank you for the further clarification.

@AarushSaharan: Sometimes it happens (to the best). Perhaps the question was too open-ended. Please, do not demotivate from posting questions and learning about this great subject.

Let us use only whole numbers between $0$ & $(m-1)$ : Each Co-efficient has $m$  choices.
Total number of Polynomials : $m^n$
Total number of Constant Polynomials : $m$
Probability : $P=1/m^{n-1}$
When we consider $m \to \infty$ , then $P \to 0$
Same Case when we consider Integers or rational numbers or real numbers.
Extending to Integers :
Consider the range of Integers between $-m$ to $+m$
Probability : $P=1/(2m+1)^{n-1}$
$P \to 0$
Extending to rational numbers :
Consider the range of rational numbers with "height" between $1$ to $m$
Probability : $P=1/h(m)^{n-1}$ , where $h(m)$ is the number of rational numbers with "height" between $1$ to $m$
$P \to 0$
Extending to real numbers :
It requires Integration & such to cover continuous variables , though End-Conclusion will be Same.
$P \to 0$

How do we make a similar argument for rational or real numbers?

I updated the answer , @AarushSaharan  , to cover 3 more cases.

Could you please explain the height concept in more detail?

Check out [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function ]] which will give Introduction to that. It is a way to count the rational numbers with finite subsets which we can make larger & larger towards infinity. Discussing in Detail will require more space than Comment Boxes !
